# Google Maps Javascript API - POI click no longer works when Transit layer is applied

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am no longer able to click on a POI after applying transit layer. This issue can be observed in sample created on its documentation site itself. [Please refer this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-transit) . Clicking a place should ideally open an info window. However this doesnt on latter link.

I am currently using frozen version of javascript API 3.22, however issue persists irrespective of API version.

Is anyone facing similar issue? I tried on different browsers and on touch devices as well. The click event works on Metro stations only.

Also tried on older version of Chrome, but no luck.

Comment: I can confirm. I would call it a bug, when there would be a documented behaviour for a click on a POI. However, you may send a bug-report/feature-request at https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Maps%20API%20v3%20-%20Bug

Comment: surprising, the issue has surfaced outside an API release cycle. This seemed to work well until a couple of days ago. Have logged this issue here - https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9555